# textbox percent formatting and unformatting

Tags: c#, winforms

In a C# windows forms class I am binding my textboxes like this.

```
this.textMargin.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("Text", dt, "Margin", true, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnValidation, 0, "P"));
```

This is fine for displaying the textbox "textMargin" as a percent. But, when I pass the value of the text box to my update statement, I get a string format error even though I am trying to use Decimal.Parse like this:

```
decimal testconvert = Decimal.Parse(this.textMargin.Text);
```

The value I am trying to pass is '100%', but it needs to submit back to the database as 1.

What is the secret here?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
string textMargin = this.textMargin.Text.EndsWith("%") ? this.textMargin.Text.Replace("%","") : this.textMargin.Text;

decimal testconvert = Decimal.Parse(textMargin) / 100;
```

Answer (score 2):

This should would work for you, using [decimal.TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.decimal.tryparse.aspx) to avoid errors and [String.Replace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk49wtc1.aspx) to remove your %.

```
decimal.TryParse(this.textMargin.Text.Replace("%", ""), out testconvert);
testconvert = testconvert / 100;
```

Answer (score 1):

`%` is not a valid part of a decimal and cannot be parsed by `Decimal.Parse`.

You will need to clear it out of the string before parsing.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see `Decimal.Parse` will not accept non-digit values, but you can use a simple algorithm like below to get rid of non-digits:

```
    public static string RemoveNonDigits(string s)
    {
        string newS = "";
        if (s.Length == 0) return newS;
        for (int i = 0; i < s.Length; i++)
        {

            if (Char.IsDigit(s[i]) || s[i] == '.')
                 newS += s[i];

            else if (!Char.IsDigit(s[i]))
            {
                newS += "";
            }

            return newS;
        }
```

Then you can call

```
Decimal percent = Decimal.Parse(RemoveNonDigits(textMargin.Text.ToString()));
```

Comment: Neither of these works with `"100%"`. Please test before posting.